# Distinct value across multiple columns

Tags: mysql-5.5, distinct

I have a table like this,

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id integer,
  col1 integer,
  col2 integer,
  col3 integer,
  col4 integer,
  col5 integer
);
INSERT INTO foo (id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
VALUES
    (322, NULL, 3, 1, 2, 2),
    (323, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2),
    (324, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
    (325, 3, 3, 3, 3, NULL);
```

I need to write a query such that I need to get

```
ID, concatinated string of unique value from the columns without null
```

My desired output should be

```
ID, UniqVal
322, "3,1,2"
323, "1,3,2"
324, "1,2"
325, "3"
```

Note: The version is MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 2):

Select each column along with the ID where the column `IS NOT NULL`. Use `UNION` to combine the result sets. This will already eliminate duplicates. Then `GROUP BY` the ID and use the [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregation function to build your list.

```
SELECT id,
       group_concat(col
                    SEPARATOR ',') uniqval
       FROM (SELECT id,
                    col1 col
                    FROM elbat
                    WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
             UNION
             SELECT id,
                    col2 col
                    FROM elbat
                    WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL
             UNION
             SELECT id,
                    col3 col
                    FROM elbat
                    WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL
             UNION
             SELECT id,
                    col4 col
                    FROM elbat
                    WHERE col4 IS NOT NULL
             UNION
             SELECT id,
                    col5 col
                    FROM elbat
                    WHERE col5 IS NOT NULL) x
       GROUP BY id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cedcc/3)

Answer (score -1):

Just for comparison if MySQL ever implements the [SQL Array type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html), you can do it like this (valid in PostgreSQL),

```
SELECT id,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT DISTINCT x
    FROM unnest(ARRAY[col1,col2,col3,col4,col5]) AS t(x)
    WHERE x IS NOT NULL
  )
FROM foo;
```

Or alternatively,

```
SELECT id, array_agg(DISTINCT x) FROM foo
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(ARRAY[col1,col2,col3,col4,col5]) AS t(x)
WHERE x IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id;
```